# Couldn't run swf file properly using Flash Player

Tags: flash

There is a flash game on this site : [game website url](http://www.4399.com/flash/110369_3.htm), the url of the swf game in this site is : [swf url of game](http://s8.4399.com/4399swf/upload_swf/ftp9/chenweihong/20130217/52a/commando3.swf), I use Chrome of old version(Flash Player supported) to open the swf url and it run properly, then I press Ctrl + Shift + I to open Dev Tools, I found that when the flash game is loading, the web requests two related resources([the screenshot of dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrxWT.png)), which are a .swf file and a .pkg file.

I downloaded those two files. I tried unzip .pkg file and I found that the .pkg file is a .SWFc file and the content in that .pkg file is a .swf file.

Then I started to fight with the .swf file... I have tried so many version of Flash Player to run that .swf file and I found that :

- When the version of Flash Player is 7, 8, I got following pic : [swf game with flash player 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvyrj.png), the content of game is changing rapidly and it looks like a old TV with all screen covered with snow. And I couldn't click any item.
- When the version of Flash Player is 9, I saw this : [swf game with flash player 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4WTp.png) , it has only a icon and the icon couldn't react when I clicked it.
- When the version of Flash Player is 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 32, 34, I saw a blank screen whit no content showed([swf game with flash player 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmymF.png)).

But when I tried open the url of that swf game([swf url of game](http://s8.4399.com/4399swf/upload_swf/ftp9/chenweihong/20130217/52a/commando3.swf)) in Flash Player directly and it can run and run perfectly.

So I want to know how could I directly open the downloaded .swf file to strat my game, is there anything I must to do with that .pkg file? If so, what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible that SWF is built with "*only network*" flag that does not allow an application to access the local drive if run locally. It is possible that SWF was URL-locked in some way or another and doesn't allow you to run locally. Simply, it is not impossible that you just won't be able to run it locally. Try setting up a local HTTP server, maybe?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Organis , I have found a solution based on your comment. I try to open the setting panel of Flash Player and find there is a setting item called "Trusted Location Setting" in "Advanced" tab, so I just add my local file path to this setting, and make that .pkg file and .swf file in the same folder, then when I click .swf, the game start to run properly!